# Using ng-include directive to bind image gallery

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular JS and highly appreciate if somebody helps me with the problem.I am trying to bind my gallery.html file to index.html row class div using ng-include directive.The problem is though the gallery is bound it isn't  responsive.Here is my code:

```
     <body ng-app='myApp'>
         <div class='container'>
            <div class='row' ng-include="'gallery.html'">
          </div>
       </div>
      <script>
           var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    </script>
  </body>
```

And here is my gallery.html code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Lights">          
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Nature">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Fjords">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Fjords">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Fjords">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class='img_container'>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Fjords">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure you're including your stylesheets, right?

Comment: Yeh, everything is ok with the stylesheets.

Comment: Then I don't see what could be possibly wrong, it is working for me on my machine. Perhaps the `.col-*` class you're using it's not being applied due to your viewport size, did your try using sm or xs columns? It must be something with your styles or bootstrap specifically, this kind of behavior has little to do with Angular... did you check in your dev tools if the bootstrap styling was applied to your elements?

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help.I'll check. :)